# How to access window.navigator.serial in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, serial-port, flutter-web, dart2js

On some browsers there exists the the property `serial` on the `window.navigator` object.

I can see it on chrome but not on safari.

How can I access that object via dart in flutter web?

`dart:html` doesn't seem to include it. Is there a way to manually extend the `window.navigator` object to include it?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I didn't access the window.navigator object from dart.

I access the serial and do all of the checks in javascript.

I use Js [context](https://fireship.io/snippets/using-js-with-flutter-web/)  to get data back from the Javascript.